# How to remove bytes from StringIO, BytesIO, etc

Tags: python

I'd like to use a BytesIO object as a continuous buffer (a common use-case). However, is it possible to remove bytes off the head that are no longer needed?

It doesn't seem like it, as there is only a truncate() method.

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_checkClosed', '_checkReadable', '_checkSeekable', '_checkWritable', 'close', 'closed', 'detach', 'fileno', 'flush', 'getvalue', 'isatty', 'next', 'read', 'read1', 'readable', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'seekable', 'tell', 'truncate', 'writable', 'write', 'writelines']
```

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot, as `BytesIO` is an in-memory version of a common file object.

As such it is treated as a sequence of bytes that can be overwritten or appended to, and just like a file removing elements from the front is not efficient as it requires a complete rewrite of all data following.

You probably want to look into the [`collections.deque()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead.

Comment: I can think of an alternative implementation, whereby the underlying IOBase object implements a series of memory chunks. Deque behavior, though not the delete behavior that I inquired about, can be emulated by just popping-off the head chunks as they are depleted... If such functionality is requested. Else, no harm done. As I'm guessing that the IOBase/BytesIO implementation already uses a series of not-necessarily-contiguous memory blocks rather than a single, contiguous memory block, I don't see this as a dramatic departure from its existing design.

Comment: `BytesIO` uses one `char *buf` object to store the data. What you want is a non-standard use of files, and the standard library doesn't offer it.

Answer (score 0):

i was looking for a way to clear the contents of BytesIO. after seeing [martijn-pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) answer, i realized that this is not possible.

however, i decided to propose a solution (**reconstruction** of BytesIO):

```
import io 

class BytesIO(io.BytesIO):
    def delete(self):
        self.close()
        super().__init__(b'')


b = BytesIO()
b.write(b'milad')
b.delete()

print(b.getvalue()) # -> b''
```

Comment: It might solve your problem, but it might produce undesirable side-effects to call the parent constructor both more than once and from somewhere other than the constructor. At the very least, it's a maintenance concern (something that might be unintentionally be broken since it's being used not as intended)